# How to override settings in php.ini and httpd.conf from my php application

Tags: php, apache, settings

I don't have any access to the php.ini and httpd.conf files. Are there any procedure to override (or add some) settings of php.ini and httpd.conf files from my php application?

Comment: Only some apache settings can be overridden by .htaccess file, only if permitted by "allow override" in apache settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Apache configuration: this can (for certain settings) be done using [`.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) files:

> `.htaccess` files (or "distributed configuration files") provide a way to make configuration changes on a per-directory basis. A file, containing one or more configuration directives, is placed in a particular document directory, and the directives apply to that directory, and all subdirectories thereof.

You may be unable to change certain settings using `.htaccess` files; the directives that you can use are specified in the main Apache configuration using [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directives.

For PHP settings: this can be done using the [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function:

> Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.

[This appendix](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) shows you which settings can be changed from scripts.

Comment: +1 for the link to that appendix, never seen it before but was pleasantly surprised to learn that short tags can be turned on and off with `ini_set`... had always assumed that setting would be immutable.

Comment: @no: that specific option, like some other, can't be altered using `ini_set`. cuz php have to parse the page before executing your `ini_set` call, and if it had that option disabled it won't be able to parse your call that's inside `<? ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) for some settings or by modifying the setting via `.htaccess`
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

The changeability of ini settings using these methods varies depending on the variable (see "Changeable" column). [This page](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) explains what each of those `PHP_INI_*` mean.

For settings in `httpd.conf` (eg: that pertain to Apache itself rather than PHP), you'll need to use [`.htaccess`](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml) files. But of course your server's `AllowOverride` has to allow you to use them. Contact your hosting provider for information on this.

Comment: and for apache (httpd.conf)??

Comment: @chanchai You can't. If you could, it would be a huge security issue, wouldn't it?

Comment: .htaccess files (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) can be used.

Comment: @Richard Then technically you aren't using PHP. And you'll also need `AllowOverride` in httpd.conf to be set to a level that lets you change settings.

Answer (score 0):

For apache, use `.htaccess`, which will grant you control over much of what would `httpd.conf` would have given you.

For PHP look here: [PHP: How to change configuration settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php), one of the method is having settings put also in the `.htaccess` file (when certain php modules exist in the server).